# How to validate instances of a class, based on their usage with shacl?

Tags: shacl

In my case there are SingleChoice (SC) and MultipleChoice (MC) questions. SC have a set of answers (as blank nodes) that must contain exectly one "points" and one "text" property. MC have a set of answers that must contain exectly one "points", one "text" and one **"pointsNegative"** property. Example as turtle:

```
prefix ex ...

ex:SC a ex:SingleChoice .
  ex:hasAnswers [
    a ex:Answer .
    ex:text "Answer 1" .
    ex:points 5 ;
  ],[ ...sameAsAbove ], ... ;

ex:MC a ex:MultipleChoice .
  ex:hasAnswers [
    a ex:Answer .
    ex:text "Answer 1" .
    ex:points 5 .
    ex:pointsNegative 1 ;
  ],[ ...sameAsAbove ], ... ;
```

I managed to write shacl rules that validate all instances of class ex:Answer. But I can't make a difference to which these instances belong (SC or MC) by validating them with these rules:

```
ex:AnswerShape
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass ex:Answer ;
  sh:property [
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:path ex:Text ;
    sh:minCount 1 ;
    sh:maxCount 1 ;
    sh:dataType xsd:string .
  ] .
```

E.g. if I add another PropertyShape for ex:pointsNegative, the shape will fail for all answers of a SC question (as these don't have ex:pointsNegative). I could omit the minCount restriction, but then answers for MC questions might have no ex:pointsNegative property.
How do I manage to have different rules executed for instances of Class ex:Answer, depending on there links (belong to SC or MC)? Is this even possible with Shacl?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1 - Create dedicated answer types

An easy solution would be to use different classes for the answers, e.g. `ex:SingleChoiceAnswer` and `ex:MultipleChoiceAnswer`. That way you can create dedicated shapes for each answer type.

```
# answers
prefix ex ...

ex:SC a ex:SingleChoice .
  ex:hasAnswers [
    a ex:SingleChoiceAnswer .
    ex:text "Answer 1" .
    ex:points 5 ;
  ],[ ...sameAsAbove ], ... ;

ex:MC a ex:MultipleChoice .
  ex:hasAnswers [
    a ex:MultipleChoiceAnswer .
    ex:text "Answer 1" .
    ex:points 5 .
    ex:pointsNegative 1 ;
  ],[ ...sameAsAbove ], ... ;

# shapes
ex:AnswerShape
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass ex:SingleChoiceAnswer ;
  sh:property [
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    ...
  ] .

ex:AnswerShape
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass ex:MultipleChoiceAnswer ;
  sh:property [
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    ...
  ] .
```

### Solution 2 - [SHACL Property Paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#property-paths)

Another solution which works without changing the original schema is to use property paths. That way you could target the choice types and declare dedicated property shapes for them.

```
# shapes
ex:SingleChoiceShape
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass ex:SingleChoice ;
  sh:property [
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:path (ex:hasAnswers ex:text)
    ...
  ] .

ex:MultipleChoice
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass ex:MultipleChoice ;
  sh:property [
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:path (ex:hasAnswer ex:pointsNegative)
    ...
  ] .
```

Comment: Many thanks for this tipp! This is a practical way to do it. Do you also know a solution without introducing specific answer classes? Validation shouldn't require to alter the actual data...

Comment: You can use SHACL property path if you don't want to change your schema. See my updated answer.